# When trying to upgrade to Rails 5, getting "Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties"" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, gemfile

I’m trying to upgrade to Rails 5.  I deleted my Gemfile.lock file, edited my Gemfile to look like below

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '5.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'addressable'
gem 'postgresql'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-modal-rails'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'compass-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
```

and ran “bundle install”, only to get the below errors

```
$ bundle install
Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-rails (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies..............
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.1.x, >= 4.0.0)

    jquery-modal-rails was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.2.0)

    jquery-rails was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

    web-console (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0)
```

How do I properly edit my Gemfile so I can upgrade to Rails 5?

Comment: The issue for me boiled down to removing the quiet_assets gem. Also, if you use rails composer, remember to type no for quiet logging. (Rails 5)

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove one of the repeated jquery-rails gem and run bundle install again.

```
// remove this line    
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Also change your gem 'coffee-rails' line for this:

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
```

I have a Rails 5 project running without problems with following Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'

# Use Capistrano for deployment

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Nothing doing.  Removed it and got the same errors.  Why would removing "jquery-rails" solve an error pertaining to "coffee-rails"?

Comment: It's to clean your Gemfile because you have 2 times the jquery-rails gem. I edited my response with another posible fix.

Comment: I used your Gemfile, but when I add back in my gems the error occurs.  I have narrowed it down to the line, "gem 'jquery-modal-rails'".  Including that causes the error on Rails 5.  Sadly, I need this gem.

Comment: I've succeed to update rails version 5 by following this answer and ran `bundle update` and `rails app:update`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall the railties gem :

```
gem install railties
```